# Moveit! installation on ROS kinetic

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to install moveit! on ROS-kinetic. But on moveit!, installation is available till indigo only.

I have already installed ROS-kinetic.

So, should i uninstall kinetic and install indigo?

I also tried to uninstall kinetic version, but the components are there in folder. Please suggest me way to do it.

Regards,
Ankita Kadam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236868/moveit!-installation-on-ros-kinetic/) by [Ankikadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27154/ankikadam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt is indeed still not released for Kinetic. It seems that the cause of this delay is a massive change to a use a single unified Git repository for all MoveIt sub-projects.

See http://discourse.ros.org/t/migration-to-one-github-repo-for-moveit/266 for details and https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit for the experimental unified repo.

So you can either try to build MoveIt for Kinetic from its sources, or indeed downgrade to either Jade or Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [Dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25986/dinesh/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-20**:
I think the main reason is actually that some of the dependencies (Octomap, FCL and some msgs) have either not been released on Xenial, or in their current released form are not compatible with MoveIt. See [ros-planning/moveit_ros#695](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/695) fi.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-20**:
And [ros-planning/moveit_core#299](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/issues/299).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-20**:
That's a valid comment @Dinesh. I left my thoughts at http://discourse.ros.org/t/migration-to-one-github-repo-for-moveit/266/21?u=130s

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-07-20**:
i've never suggested we delay the moveit kinetic release for the repo merge, but if they could coincide that would be nice

**Comment by [Ankikadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27154/ankikadam/) on 2016-07-20**:
Currently i downgraded to indigo as currently this is in learning phase for me. I will shift to Kinetic once it is released for Moveit!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/18 for kinetic release details

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1